# Pydantic union discriminator based on filed on parent model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

i have model like this:

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    protocol: str
    protocol_params: Union[ProtoclOneParam, ProtocolTwoParam]
```

`ProtoclOneParam` and `ProtocolTwoParam` have no same field with distinguishable value so I can use them as `Discriminator` and the only way that I can understand which model should be used for `protocol_params` is through the value of `protocol` which can either be `"protocol1"` or `"protocol2"`.

if `protocol == "protocol1"` then `protocol_params` should be deserialized using the `ProtoclOneParam` model and so on.

in actual use cases, there are more than 5 protocols without any distinguishable field among them.

is there any way in pedantic to achieve what I need?

Comment: I assume you have good reasons to not use a discriminated union. In that case you can maybe just work with a simple registry dict and a `field_validator`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only option should be using `field_validator` as @axel-donath correctly mentioned.

So here it is:

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    protocol: str
    protocol_params: Union[ProtoclOneParam, ProtocolTwoParam]

    @field_validator("protocol_params", mode="plain")
    def set_protocol_validation_model(v, vlidation_info:ValidationInfo):
        vals = vlidation_info.data
        if vals["protocol"] == 'protocol1':
            return ProtoclOneParam.model_validate(v)
        ...
```

**Note** that the `protocol` field should be defined on top of `protocol_params` so that in its validator the value of `protocol` can be accessible through `vlidation_info.data`.